# How to avoid CSS impact to dynamically added classes

Tags: html, css

**What actually happens**: I have a `div` in a file there is HTML code, which added Dynamically from BackEnd, CSS Classes(which included from Dynamic code) uses CSS from my `style.css`

**What I need**: My own CSS should not impact on dynamically added code.

**Similar Solution**: `iframe` is a solution but I want to do same using `div` tag.

[image]

Comment: That won't be possible unless you set up some different css selectors.

Comment: Just use other class name?

Comment: Can you give an example of code after the dynamic load? State what was already there and what was loaded in. You might just need to give a unique identifier to the containers and style accordingly.

Comment: @Swellar, I don't know what code/classes will be added there..

Comment: Use class name that is not in `style.css`? I'm pretty sure styles in there are already defined, so don't use any names from there

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Gezzasa, Dynamic code added by users, so there is no control from my side.. they are using `row` class and same using by Bootstrap.. I can  change neither Dynamic code nor Bootstrap CSS

Comment: @om. You could namespace all of your classes, for example prefix them with `omscode-`... Or if you're still building the html, you could try a header that goes across, then 3 columns (center one is the dynamic content) and then the footer. Then apply your styles only to the id's on the sections which aren't dynamically loaded... Or, you could apply a reset/invert/undo of all you styles where you set them all to default/0/none as appropriate on the dynamic content wrapper so it's contents have full control of all element styles. No shortcut for this one yet that I know of. :\

Comment: @om. Sorry, here's a solid option for you, the `:not` selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot

Comment: Are those elements supposed to have styles or should they be virgin of all sort of styling ?

Comment: @ Pierre Burton, Those can have their own inline style or style sheet linked in Dynamic code

Answer (score 0):

I think this is:

```
<div class="row" style="all:initial"> do some thing</div>
```

Comment: this `div class="row"` is added by website users/customers, I can't do anything in Dynamic added code ..

Answer (score 0):

Better you can write you css with parent-child combination to avoid such issues as like below snippet. Here newly added `<p>` tag has same class `.content` but parent has different class name as `.dynamic` from `.static`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.dynamic').html(jQuery(".static").html());
});
```

```css
.static .content {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="static">
  <p class="content">Some content goes here</p>
</div>
<div class="dynamic">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Three options from my perspective:

**1. Use unique classnames**

**2. Unique ID**

If only classes are added, give the parent div an ID and overwrite the css by using the ID.

```
<div id="uniqueStyle" class="dynamicDiv">
    <div class="row clearfix"></div>
    <div class="row clearfix"></div>
    <div class="row clearfix"></div>
    <div class="row clearfix"></div>
</div>

#uniqueStyle{
 background: red; //overwrite
}

#uniqueStyle .row{
background: blue; //overwrite
}
```

**3. Using :not**

Give the div an unique ID and use the :not selector to exclude it from styling.

```
<div id="noStyling" class="dynamicDiv">
   <div class="row clearfix"></div>
   <div class="row clearfix"></div>
   <div class="row clearfix"></div>
   <div class="row clearfix"></div>
</div>

:not(#noStyling){
   background: blue; //set styling of all elements except #noStyling
}
```

More info about :not selector: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp